# Unable to update value in vue-google-autocomplete in a Vue 3 Project

Tags: vue.js

**Edited**: After reading @Ali Bahrami's asnwer

I am using [vue-google-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete) in a Vue 3 project. It works fine, provides addresses and allows me to select an address and I am able to pick the selected and save it the database. This is the code for the `<vue-google-autocomplete>`

```
<vue-google-autocomplete
    ref="autoCompleteAddress"
    id="location"
    classname="form-control"
    placeholder="Location"
    v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
    country="ca"
 >
 </vue-google-autocomplete>
```

Later, I want to display the address that I saved in the database (e.g. 1 Bloor Street, Toronto') in the `<vue-google-autocomplete>`. However, I am unable to do so. I tried the following code in mounted(). (I use options API)

```
 this.$nextTick(() => {
        let location = document.getElementById("location");
        console.log("typeof location " + typeof location);
        // It enters 'else'
        if (location) {
            location.value = "1 Bloor Street, Toronto";
        } else {
            console.log("location does not exist 0 ");
        }

        if (typeof location === 'object') {
           // location.value = "1 Bloor Street, Toronto";
           // Results in error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
        } else {
            console.log("location does not exist 1");
        }

        console.log(typeof this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"]);
        if (this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"]) {
            this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"].update(
                "1 Bloor Street, Toronto"
            );
        } else {
            console.log('this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"] does not exits');
        }
        // For testing 
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                let location = document.getElementById("location");
                console.log("typeof location in setTimeout" + typeof location);
                if (location) {
                    location.value = "1 Bloor Street, Toronto";
                } else {
                    console.log("location does not exist in setTimeout");
                }
            }.bind(this),
            1000
        );

    });
```

This is the output I see in console:

```
typeof location object
location does not exist 0 
undefined
this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"] does not exits
typeof location in setTimeoutobject
location does not exist in setTimeout
```

Surprisingly, the true test for the the first if failes (`if (location)`). If I force `document.getElementById("location").value = '1 Bloor Street, Toronto';` command displays an error: **createEvent.vue:545 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at Proxy.** Surprisingly, when I use the same command in console, it works and updates the `vue-auto-complete` text box.
Similarly, I get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')" for `this.$refs["autoCompleteAddress"].update('1 Bloor Street, Toronto')`. And, surprisingly, this command too works in console.

For testing purpose, I tried to update 'location' after 1000 m secs, however, it still fails.

I am confused -- why `if (location)` fails and I am unable to change `location.value`, though it works in console.

Any suggestions, how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was able to update location value using `location.value` through console, it appears that it is a timing issue. So, I experimented with setTimeout(), and it appears that after about 1500 m secs, `location.value' starts working. To be on the safe side, I am using a delay of 2.5 secs, as show here in mounted().

```
 this.$nextTick(() => {
        setTimeout(
            function () {
                const location = document.getElementById("location");
                if (location) {
                    location.value = "1 Bloor Street, Toronto";
                } else {
                    console.log("location does not exist... ");
                }
            }.bind(this),
            2500
        );
    });
```

Instead of hard coding the delay, I use a timer of 500 m sec. I check if 'location' is available in the timer event. As soon as the location becomes available, I stop the timer and use `location.value` to update the address. I have noticed that on the server running on my Mac, it takes 2 to 3 cycles (of 500 ms) to become ready, but is much faster on the server running on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, nextTick, ref } from 'vue';

const autoCompleteAddress = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  nextTick(() => {
    const location = document.getElementById("location");
    if (location) {
      location.value = '1 Bloor Street, Toronto';
    }
    if (autoCompleteAddress.value) {
      autoCompleteAddress.value.update('1 Bloor Street, Toronto');
    }
  })
});
</script>

<template>
<vue-google-autocomplete
    :ref="autoCompleteAddress"
    id="location"
    classname="form-control"
    placeholder="Location"
    v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
    country="ca"
 >
</vue-google-autocomplete>
</template>
```

I'm assuming you are using `script setup` format. in vue 3 composition api, `this` keyword is not used any more.

see the code and notify for any needed change.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Ali Bahrami. I will try your code -- I am sure that this will work. No, I am not using composition API (I use options API). I will try to modify your code for options API.

Comment: I tried the code suggested by @Ali Bahrami, however, I am unable to make it work. Please see the updated qestion.